# Using WHERE with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm getting a syntax error for the WHERE clause in the following code.
Whats the problem?

```
CREATE PROC spIncreaseHours
(@ID int, @HoursPerWeek DEC, @HourlyRate INT)
AS
INSERT INTO Payments
Values (@HoursPerWeek, @HourlyRate)
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? You cannot use `WHERE` with an `INSERT`

Comment: I want to insert HoursPerWeek and HourlyRate into a row for a given ID.

Comment: Then insert the ID too

Comment: A where clause targets rows in a table, you are inserting data, not updating or deleting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to UPDATE:

```
CREATE PROC spIncreaseHours
(@ID int, @HoursPerWeek DEC, @HourlyRate INT)
AS
UPDATE Payments set 
HoursPerWeek = @HoursPerWeek, 
HourlyRate = @HourlyRate
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `WHERE` with an `INSERT`. You either want to be inserting a new row, or updating an existing one. For example `INSERT`:

```
CREATE PROC spIncreaseHours
(@ID int, @HoursPerWeek DEC, @HourlyRate INT)
AS
INSERT INTO Payments
Values (@ID, @HoursPerWeek, @HourlyRate);
```

Or `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE PROC spIncreaseHours
(@ID int, @HoursPerWeek DEC, @HourlyRate INT)
AS
UPDATE Payments
SET HoursPerWeek = @HoursPerWeek, 
     HourlyRate = @HourlyRate
WHERE ID = @ID;
```

Of course, there is also a third possibility where you don't know if a row for `@ID` already exists, so you can do a check first:

```
CREATE PROC spIncreaseHours
(@ID int, @HoursPerWeek DEC, @HourlyRate INT)
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Payments WHERE ID = @ID)
    UPDATE Payments
    SET HoursPerWeek = @HoursPerWeek, 
        HourlyRate = @HourlyRate
    WHERE ID = @ID;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO Payments
    Values (@ID, @HoursPerWeek, @HourlyRate);
```